# WPF - setting datagridcell background AND horizontal alignment messes up background

Tags: c#, xaml, background, alignment, wpfdatagrid

Via multibinding I was able to set the background of specific cells. However, I want to set the horizontalalignment of the  cell text to right, but that messes up the **background color** that is supposed to **stretch** the complete background (not the aligned text only):

[image: bad background]

Here's the minified (runnable) code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Test> MyData { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;
        MyData = Test.GetData();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ColOne { get; set; }
    public string ColTwo { get; set; }

    public static ObservableCollection<Test> GetData()
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<Test>
        {
            new Test { Title = "HO", ColOne = "3.20", ColTwo = "5.85"},
            new Test { Title = "DOR", ColOne = "-3.33", ColTwo = "5.9"}
        };
    }
}
```

and the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="ColorColumnAlignment.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyData}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Style.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Chocolate"></Setter>
                    </Style.Setters>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I've seen someone with a similar problem, but I don't understand what he tries to explain as his solution ([WPF: DataGridCell override the row style color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479341/wpf-datagridcell-override-the-row-style-color))

-- update: setting the HorizontalContentAlignment does **not** help completely, it results in this (the alignment of right is gone somehow):

[image: Stays aligned left]

Comment: Swap `HorizontalAlignment` with `HorizontalContentAlignment`

Comment: @ChrisW. No that doesn't help. It stays aligned to the left, I already tried that

Comment: Oh sorry, try TextAlignment, I don't recall though if that properties available thought, otherwise you might want to consider just making a copy of (or) editing the default style template for it to fit your needs.

Comment: @ChrisW. TextAlignment isn't part of the properties for DataGridCell.

Comment: Ya I didn't think so, but didn't take the time to check either. I would go ahead and look into the [default templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066(v=vs.95).aspx) where we'll see the ContentPresenter bound to HorizontalContentAlignment for its HorizontalAlignment. You may just want to specify your own Template to accomplish your goals.

Comment: I'll have to invest some time in that :/ I'm currently not used to doing that. Meanwhile, if anyone else has a solution, it's more than welcome!

Comment: just see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177153/text-alignment-in-datagrid

Answer (score 2):

Change your TargetType and your Setter Property to the examples in your modified code below :

```
<Window x:Class="ColorColumnAlignment.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyData}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Chocolate" />
                    </Style.Setters>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Text}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Foreground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide the explanation as well.